# Issue with favicon on gtecher

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I have an issue with a favicon on my website where my favicon comes to show everywhere I need but It does not show on Google search results when I search gtechertip instead of this wordpress icon shows.

I have seen other results on stack overflow related to this but none matched my case
Website : text
I am not a developer I am just trying to use wordpress but every method I used to solve this was unsuccessful.

Pls help me solve this issue.